# Removing new lines spaces in variable/if

Tags: php

i have some script, i have form, then i get info with $_POST and send informations on email.

I use this:

```
if($ccm == "")
{
    $ccm = "";
}else{
    $ccm = "CCM: <font style='font-family: Calibri; font-size: 17px;'>" . $ccm . "</font>";
}
```

So if user didn't enter answer in field "ccm", $ccm will be empty, if user entered something then $ccm will be shown. It works ok for now i think, maybe there is some way to do that what i did above, but problem is, when $ccm is empty and i get line spaces in email message, so how to do it to lose line spaces in message?

Thaks

Comment: why are you even sending email if its empty

Comment: Please post the message-producing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing about the code you haven't shown, it sounds like you should add your `<br>` or `<p>` to `$ccm` in that if/else block, instead of unconditionally appending (e.g.) `$ccm . '<br>'` to the message string later on.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are looking for this

```
if(empty($ccm))
{
    $ccm = "";
}
else
{
    $ccm = "CCM: <font style='font-family: Calibri; font-size: 17px;'>" . $ccm . "</font>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!trim($ccm)) { /* .. */ }
```

Get rid of whitespaces